# how to map image array with filter in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm absolutely beginner in ReactJS and I want to filter and map

```
    const Shop = [
        {
            img : jam, 
            category: 'jam'
        },
        {
            img : headset,
            category:'headset'
        },
        {
            img : sepatu,
            category:'sepatu'
        }
    ];
    
    let ShopItem = [
        {
            id : 1,
            img : jam,
            category : 'jam',
            price : 'Rp. 900,000'
        },
        {
            id : 2,
            img : jam,
            category : 'jam',
            price : 'Rp. 900,000'
        },
        {
            id : 3,
            img : headset,
            category : 'headset',
            price : 'Rp. 900,000'
        }
    ]

    function Content(){
    const [shopItems,toogleshopItems]=useState(false);
    let [items,showItems]=useState('');

    const toogleShop = ()=>{
        toogleshopItems(!shopItems);
        console.log(shopItems);
        
    }

    

    function showshopItems(){
        return(
            <>
                {Shopitem.map((shopitem, shopitemIndex) => {
        return Shop.map((shop, shopIndex) => {
          if (shop.category == shopitem.category)
            return <img className="image-place" src={shopitem.img} />;
        });
      })}
          </>
        )
    
    }

    return(
    <>
        <div className="content">
            
            <div className="content-wrapper">
                <div className="content-title">Browse Categories</div>
                <div className="image-flex">
                    {
                    Shop.map((shops)=>
                        <React.Fragment key={shops.category}>
                        <img onClick={toogleShop}  className="image-place" src={shops.img}/>
                        
                        
                    </React.Fragment>
                    
                    )}
                    
                </div>
                <hr/>
                {shopItems? showshopItems() : console.log("no") }
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
    )
}

export default Content
```

how to map shopitem image that has the same category value with shop category value...

[when I click picture watch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUrFP.jpg)
if I click the picture 1 it will show child picture that has category jam

Comment: Welcome to SO. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Code that you've worked on to solve the problem should include a [mcve], and be included in your question.

Comment: It doesn't clear what's the problem!

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. You should put in an honest effort and show us what you've tried already on your own, and ***then*** post a question with an example of your code and clear details about any issues, bugs, errors, warnings, and include what you've done to debug already and a set of steps to reproduce the issue if that is relevant.

Comment: Additionally, why not just use the `img` property of `ShopItem` elements that has the same value as the those in the `Shop` array elements?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found out whats your problem. You should have a `state` for getting current category when user clicks on the top image and filter the items based on the `state`. I've created a sample based on your request:

```
export default function App() {
  const [currentCategory, setCategory] = useState();

  const TopSlide = () => {
    return (
      <div className="topSlide">
        {Shop.map((shop, index) => {
          return (
            <img
              alt=""
              className="topSlideImage"
              src={shop.img}
              onClick={() => {
                setCategory(shop.category);
              }}
            />
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  };

  const DownSlide = () => {
    return (
      <div className="downSlide">
        {ShopItem.filter((x) => x.category === currentCategory).map(
          (shop, index) => {
            return <img alt="" className="downSlideImage" src={shop.img} />;
          }
        )}
      </div>
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      {TopSlide()}
      <hr />
      {DownSlide()}
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit vigilant-cloud-cff15]

Comment: doesn't work it display all photo, have other way?

Comment: Based on your question, this is the answer. What's the condition would like to filter with?

Comment: Do you have telegram?

Comment: Please leave your id, I will send a message.